# internal server error richfaces icons

Tags: ajax, sorting, jsf, richfaces

In one of my environments i have this error :

GET http://host/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.iconimages.DataTableIconSortNone/DATB/eAFjYGD4!!8!AAYAAv4_.jsf 500 (Internal Server Error)
viewDocumentDetails.jsf:371 
GET http://host/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.iconimages.DataTableIconSortNone/DATB/eAFjYGD4!!8!AAYAAv4_.jsf 500 (Internal Server Error)
viewDocumentDetails.jsf:1

GET http://host/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.GradientA/DATB/eAH7!!3Tj2v7mAAZZAV3.jsf 500 (Internal Server Error)

in fact in richfaces table the sort icon is not loaded... but in local environment it is ok

do you know what can be the issue and how to fix it please ?

thank you !!!